# javascript - functions and equations confusion

Tags: javascript, equations

```
 var number = prompt('Input a number!');
 var n = number;
   function getList() {


 for (var n = 1; n <= 17; n++) {


   if (n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0) 
     console.log (n);
   }
 }


console.log(getList());
console.log((n*(n+1))/2);

//equation for summation: (n*(n+1))/2
```

I'm trying to return the sum of numbers divisible by 3 or 5 up to 17. So far, it half-works; it lists all the numbers, but I can't find a way to return the sum.

I have the equation for summation, but I can't find a way to put it in so that it works. How do you get the equation to reference the list instead of referencing the inputted number?

The answer is supposed to be 60. Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: Just write a for loop to calculate the sum!

Comment: answer is 60 for what input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Just return the sum from your `getList` function
2. Make sure your prompt input is **converted to integer** otherwise it will be treated as a string and your `n*(n+1)/2` will be wrong

```js
var number = parseInt(prompt('Input a number!'));
var n = number;

function getList() {
  var sum = 0;
  
  for (var n = 1; n <= 17; n++) {
    if (n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0) {
      console.log (n);
      sum += n;
    }
  }
  
  return sum;
}


console.log(getList());
console.log(n, (n*(n+1))/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var sum = 0;
for (var n = 1; n <= 17; n++) {
   if (n % 3 === 0 || n % 5 === 0) 
     sum += n;
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to add the numbers and return it after for loop.

Below it the exapmle.

```js
function getList() {
  var sum = 0;

  for (var n = 1; n <= 17; n++) {
    if (n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0) {
      sum += n;
    }
  }
  
  return sum;
}


console.log(getList());
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution, as the OP asked *How to return the sum*. Then, use the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an equation :)

```js
function sumOfNumbersDivisibleBy3Or5(n) {
   const by3 = Math.floor(n/3),
         by5 = Math.floor(n/5),
         by3And5 = Math.floor(n/3/5);

  return 3*by3*(by3+1)/2 + 5*by5*(by5 + 1)/2 - 3*5*by3And5*(by3And5 + 1)/2
}

console.log(sumOfNumbersDivisibleBy3Or5(17))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var number = prompt('Input a number!');
 function getList() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var n = 1; n <= number; n++) {
   if (n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0) 
     sum+=n;
   }
  return sum;
 }
console.log(getList());
```

it will return sum of all the number which is divisible by 3 or 5 in between 1 and entered number